# Dynamically set binding in aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I want to achieve something like this in Aurelia:

> pseudo code:

```
<template>
   <div repeat.for="column of columns">
     <input value.bind="company.[column]">
   </div>
</template>
```

I guess I would need to do something like this:

https://github.com/aurelia/framework/issues/102

But was wondering if there maybe is a simpler or more straightforward way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, all you have to do is remove the dot between company and column:

`<input value.bind="company[column]">`

Here's a [GistRun Example](https://gist.run/?id=d264f941366543dd9117ec90e7f1a712)

Comment: That's just plain JavaScript.

Comment: Shame on me ;-)